# Likelihood equations returning different values in R

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio

I made mechanistic adjustments to a negative binomial likelihood equation to account for the distribution of whole network sizes, `Y` generated from branching processes with mean `R` and dispersion `k`. I optimize the likelihood/MLE using either `optim()` or surface/profile likelihood methods depending on the application.

**My question is R code-based, but believe this is a better forum for the question.** Please let me know if it is more appropriate for Stack Overflow, however.

For context, the original modified PDF is:

1. $P(Y=y)=\frac{\Gamma(ky+y-1)}{\Gamma(ky)\Gamma(y+1)}\frac{{\frac{R}{k}^{y-1}}}{(1+\frac{R}{k})^{ky+y-1}}$

I have been optimizing this without issue for a while now, but this assumes each branching process starts with one individual. Sometimes the multiple branching processes overlap and we can't tease them apart, so in a second modification I conditioned on the number of overlapping networks, `n`:

2. $P(Y=y|n)=(\frac{n}{y})\frac{\Gamma(ky+y-n)}{\Gamma(ky)\Gamma(y-n+1)}\frac{{\frac{R}{k}^{y-n}}}{(1+\frac{R}{k})^{ky+y-n}}$

When using the second equation and assume all `n` values equal 1, the two formulas should give the same values. This is true, except *when the probability gets exceedingly low, then R returns values of `-Inf` or `NaN` for equation 2, but not for equation 1.* This prevents me from optimizing the likelihood using either method.

Is there a solution or trick to avoid this? Scouring the internet yields no information. Below I am providing the smallest snippet of code possible to recreate the problem.

```r
#Equation 1 (Unconditioned PDF)
nb_y1 <- function(y,R,k) {
  logpy1 <- lgamma(k*y+(y-1))-(lgamma(k*y)+lgamma(y+1))+(y-1)*log(R/k)-(k*y+(y-1))*log(1+R/k)
  return(logpy1)                                               
}

#Equation 2 (Conditioned PDF)
nb_yn <- function(y,n,R,k) {
  logpyn <- log(n) - log(y) + lgamma(k*y+y-n) - lgamma(k*y) - lgamma(y-n+1) + log((R/k)^(y-n)/(1+R/k)^(k*y+y-n))
  return(logpyn)                                               
}

#Mean R=0.9, dispersion k=0.25
y1 <- nb_y1(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,50,500,1000),0.9,0.25)
yn <- nb_yn(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,50,500,1000),rep(1,10),0.9,0.25) #Assume all n=1

#should be same number, but 500 returns -Inf and 1000 returns NaN in equation 2
y1
yn

# y1
# [1] -0.3815141 -2.3944450 -3.1546129 -3.6477180 -4.0159042 -4.3106037 -4.5566351 -7.6172575 -11.5894417 -13.1963657
# yn
# [1] -0.3815141 -2.3944450 -3.1546129 -3.6477180 -4.0159042 -4.3106037 -4.5566351 -7.6172575 -Inf         NaN
```

Comment: I haven't tested anything, but one thing that leaps out immediately is that you haven't made complete use of the logarithm in equation 2: do not take powers or divide, but instead do all that in terms of the logs.  That helps reduce overflow and underflow.

Comment: THANK YOU! That is the issue. I have spent days on this and didnt even notice I forgot to change part of the code. If you would like to move this to a formal answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Or you can now answer it (in the answer box) yourself, to close the question ...